# Local User Preferences

Tags: customization

I'm having a rough time getting blender (2.79) to play nice with user preferences.  Per the documentation @ https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html:

> For locally extracted Blender distributions, the user configuration
>   and runtime data are kept in the same sub-directory, allowing multiple
>   Blender versions to run without conflict, ignoring the USER and SYSTEM
>   files.

However, with a locally extracted version of blender (I have both an installed and an extracted version of blender, both 2.79), it refuses to use a local preferences file, rather it is using the "global" or system-based user preferences file.

This was a big hit to my DCC station's setup, as I wasn't expecting this behavior.  I made a TON of changes in the locally extracted version, not expecting those changes to affect the installed version.  Now we've lost a highly customized base user-preferences file.  My bad...

Alas, I need to figure out how to force blender to use a local preferences file, and not modify the system based preferences.  I don't feel like hitting my self in the face with a brick.

I'm not sure if I should submit a bug report about this, as well?  I assume I've made a mistake, yet the official documentation literally states the intended behavior is for locally extracted versions to use local configurations and runtime data, to AVOID conflicts like this.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the fast reply, and I'm glad it was a simple thing.

This begs the question...  Why does official documentation say that locally extracted (portable) versions of blender have this behavior out-of-the-box, when in fact user action is required to force the behavior...

That documentation should be updated!

Anyhow, thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably the ever continuing plague of incomplete documentation. Good news is that being open source, you can suggest edits and improve it yourself.

Comment: I haven't looked properly, but if there is a difference between what the documentation tells you and what you have to do, you can report a bug here: https://developer.blender.org/